# Table View Cell Height Shrinks After Partial Swipe of Cell

Tags: ios, swift

Table View Controller using SwipeCellKit

Set row height using

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0 //allows row size to expand
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Also tried:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight =  UITableView.automaticDimension
```

The cell height is correct when I open the tableviewcontroller.
When I swipe left but decide not to delete the cell when I click again the cell size will shrink to two lines.
If I leave the table view controller and come back the cell height is once again correct.

Video Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tbJb0XrrjWQ3An-bc_XdZfPPNLg6tXlD/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 270
```

Give the `estimatedRowHeight` a higher value instead of using `UITableView.automaticDimension`

Add the below table view delegate methods to your code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableView.automaticDimension
```

}

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableView.automaticDimension
```

}

Hope that in the storyboard you have given proper (`top, bottom, leading and trailing`) constraints for the label inside the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately did not work.... Ended up removing SwipeCellKit and just creating the swipe action myself and that has resolved the issue.